# Android: is there a way to apply a right-margin span within an edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm looking for something similar to LeadingMarginSpan, but capable of applying both left- and right- margins to the text, as opposed to just a left margin.

What I'm trying to do is have the option of making some paragraphs narrower than others within the same edittext, so it might looks something like this:

```
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah

     blah blah blah blah blah blah
     blah blah blah blah blah blah
     blah blah blah blah blah blah
     blah

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
```

As far as I know there are no pre-defined spans that do this, and I don't know how to go about creating a new span from scratch that could do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A work around for your specific case would be to use three different TextViews, the middle one having more padding. Too bad there's no `TrailingMarginSpan`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't set right padding/margin with span. But you can cheat with `MetricAffectingSpan`.
It has two methods: `updateMeasureState` (called when measuring text) and `updateDrawState` (called when drawing text).

So, if you increase textScaleX at measuring, android will make shorter lines. If you don't increase textScaleX when drawing, android will not scale lines when drawing. As a result, you'll get shorter lines. That will look like right padding.

It's not perfect: you can't set right padding in pixels, but you will have some padding on right.

Here is 5% right padding example.

```
public class RoughtRightPaddingSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
        p.setTextScaleX(1.05f);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know there are no pre-defined spans that do this

AFAIK, you are correct.

> and I don't know how to go about creating a new span from scratch that could do it.

Well, support for `LeadingMarginSpan` is baked into `Layout` and `StaticLayout`, so simply creating a `TrailingMarginSpan` will be insufficient. You would have to create your own custom subclasses of `Layout` and `StaticLayout`, overriding and cloning their very complicated `draw()` methods, and pour in your `TrailingMarginSupport`.

In short, this will be painful.

If you happen to be making your own firmware, of course, this becomes much simpler... :-)

Comment: `>You would have to create your own custom subclasses of Layout and StaticLayout, overriding and cloning their very complicated draw() methods, and pour in your TrailingMarginSupport.`

That might just be what I'll have to do. I'm on my way out the door right now, but if I can get that to work, I'll come back and post details.

Comment: Sorry I took longer to get back to this than I expected. Android.text.Layout does have code that looks like it could be overridden to handle right- as well as left-margins, but the problem is that TextView's Layout object is private and cannot be modified or set, so writing my own class extending of Layout would be pointless because there's no way to get it into TextView. The only option I can think of is to copy all of TextView into my app, but that's not really viable because TextView calls internal classes that aren't directly accessible to developers.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the help. At least it's reassuring to know that right-margin spans really aren't implemented, and I'm not crazy for not being able to do it.

Comment: @Andrew: No, you are not crazy. At least not with respect to this. I cannot speak regarding your sanity on other topics... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to a webview instead on TextView

With webview you could use html-tag which offeres much more formatting options

Comment: It also is a much more expensive widget in terms of memory consumption. `WebView` is a problem when placed in other scrollable containers, like a `ListView`. Also, the OP did not say he wanted to *display* this text -- perhaps he wants to edit it in an `EditText`.

Comment: That's correct. The text I'm trying to format needs to be editable by the user, so using a webview isn't an option (which is unfortunate, as I've run into quite a few situations where being able to use HTML would have saved me a lot of trouble)

Comment: In this case you either find a good open source project of an editor already having this feature or to be enhanced to do so. Or you have to do all from the basics (I would guess 4-8 weeks of work). Maybe you need to check the sources of EditText